# getJSON to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, getjson

I need to get content from this Json url and create an array with the following format:

> var locations = [
>         ['Bondi Beach', -30.890542, 151.274856],
>         ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
>         ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
>         ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
>         ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
>       ]

And here is my code... what could I be missing?

**Updated:**

```
    var locations = new Array();
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON('c.js', function(jsonDados) {
                    $.each(jsonDados, function(key, valor) {                                
                            $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + valor.city + ' : ' + valor.latitude + ' , ' + valor.longitude +'</li>');
                            locations[key] = [valor.city, valor.latitude, valor.longitude];
                    });
            });
            window.alert (locations);
    });
```

**Solved**

```
    var locations = new Array();
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON('http://www.xxxxxx/index.php', function(jsonDados) {
                    $.each(jsonDados, function(key, valor) {                                
                            $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + valor.city + ' : ' + valor.latitude + ' , ' + valor.longitude +'</li>');
                            locations.push([valor.city, valor.latitude, valor.longitude]);
                    });
```

However, I needed to add all my code inside this function. Now it works fine.

Comment: What is the observed result?

Comment: http://www.jucees.es.gov.br/api/v1/estatisticaConsultas

Comment: This is only a portion of code to populate my Array. This Array is used by entire code to create each mark point and click information in the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get by ajax request json from `http://www.jucees.es.gov.br/api/v1/estatisticaConsultas/index.php` because it don't have [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) header in response.

Also you have syntax error `{ val.city, val.latitude, val.longitude }`. Change `{` and `}` to array `[` and `]`.

Comment: I did... it is working as describe in SOLVED.

http://www.jucees.es.gov.br/api/v1/estatisticaConsultas